# AWS Lightsail website logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am currently using an AWS Lightsail with a Bitnami image to host a website for searching donors. I would like to enable logging of the IP addresses of users that use the website. I am not sure how to connect to existing AWS services like Cloudwatch to log these accesses, however. Is there a way to integrate the logs or will I need to manually read the server logs via ssh from the Lightsail instance itself?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you would have to manually read it from application logs. This is not available via cloudwatch.

Comment: From personal experience it is also not possible to install AND use the CloudWatch Agent on Lightsail.